# Definition of boundary in a topological invariant way

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm reading through Aguilar & Prieto lecture notes "Fiber bundles" (available online by googling it, here:http://paginas.matem.unam.mx/cprieto/index.php/es/archivos-2/libros?download=11:fiber-bundles).

Since I need to look up everything I don't know (and this shows up very much early on) I started to look for a definition of boundary of a topological space.

Page 2 defines it as:
$$ Bd(M)=\{x\in M| H_2(M,M-x)=0\} $$
Looking up on books I couldn't manage to find where this comes from. On the internet I've found something similar called excision or relative homology.

Can someone help me find good resources for this definition. 
Thanks

Comment: Tha is not the definition of boundary for a general space: they are talking about the Moebius strip and that condition works pretty much only for surfaces. For manifolds of dimension $n$ you have to change the $2$ for $n$.

Comment: You should look up any good treatement of the basic (co)homology of manifolds; the book by Greenberg and Harper is a nice one. The way your question is phrased does not make it clear what you know, exactly: adding details about your background will surely not hurt.

Comment: yes, thanks. I forgot. I do have some knowledge on homology and cohomology groups, not very much in depth, though. Also, fiber bundles, Mayer Vietoris. I still need to read about CW complexes.  I did suspect that one has to change the 2 for the top dimension. In any case, the book by Greenberg and Harper doesn't seem to include that particular formulation of boundary I'm referring to, even though it treats standard topics that i will be reading.

Comment: I've never seen that as the *definition* of boundary of an $n$-manifold $M$ (with the $2$ changed to $n$). The way I've seen boundary and interior defined is using basepointed coordinate charts with values in $\{p \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid p_n \ge 0\}$, where the basepoint is in $\{p_n=0\}$ for the boundary and in $\{p_n>0\}$ for the interior. Then one proves that $x$ is in the boundary iff $H_n(M,M-x;Z/2)=0$ and in the interior iff $H_n(M,M-x;Z/2)=Z/2$.

Comment: Thanks @LeeMosher. That means that standard treatment first defines it as you mentioned and then include a proposition relating it to the relative homology. Unfortunately, I can't afford to go through all of the theory of relative homology, I need to justify that claim. I can't find this exact application easily in the books (by the way, the ;Z/2 part still puzzles me). Could you please point out where I can find this claim and in what book? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, you should ignore the $\mathbb{Z}/2$ part; you can just use the old familiar $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is an $n$-manifold with boundary then there are two relevant formulas:

- If $x$ is an interior point of $M$ then 
  $$H_n(M,M-x) \approx H_n(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n-0) \approx \mathbb{Z}
  $$

The first $\approx$ is proved by applying the excision theorem using a manifold coordinate chart near $x$. The second $\approx$ is proved in any algebraic topology textbook around the same place that you find the computation $H_n(S^n) \approx \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge} = \{p \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid p_n \ge 0\}$.

- If $x$ is a boundary point of $M$ then 
  $$H_n(M,M-x) \approx H_n(\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge}, \mathbb{R}^n_{\ge} - 0) \approx 0
  $$

Again the first $\approx$ is proved by applying the excision theorem together with a boundary-of-a-manifold-with-boundary coordinate chart near $x$. The second $\approx$ is an exercise (the inclusion of $\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge}-0$ into $\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge}$ is a homotopy equivalence).